# Event created via composite API not showing up in Contact's activity timeline

Tags: rest-api, event, composite, unique-field, activity-timeline

We're seeing an issue with Events created via the composite API where one duplicate event in the composite batch is causing the other non-duplicate events to be only partially created, without their attendees.  Below are sample API requests and responses that demonstrate the issue.

We have a unique, case-insensitive custom field called `Event_Hash__c` on the Activity object whose purpose is to prevent duplicate Events from being created by race conditions that could occur in an upstream data integration. The integration is responsible for supplying the value to the custom field, which will be a unique value computed by the integration platform.  If a race condition occurs such that the integration tries to insert an Event with an `Event_Hash__c` value that already exists in Salesforce, we expect the Salesforce API to reject the individual insert request, but properly process non-duplicate inserts.

Using the composite API, we are seeing that composite batches where no duplicates are being inserted are completing as expected, but composite batches that include one or more duplicate records in the payload are returning the responses we expect, but that the Event objects that are successfully created are being created without EventRelation relation records. It would seem as though a `DUPLICATE_VALUE` failure in the composite request is causing the successful records to only be partially created, and the step to create EventRelation records is getting skipped.

```
# Event activity does show up in contact 0035c00002TOjhQAAT timeline
# EventRelation record with RelationId 0035c00002TOjhQAAT exists for EventId 00U5c00000S5MptEAF
POST /services/data/v53.0/composite/sobjects
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "event"
            },
            "Description": "Sample description",
            "StartDateTime": "2023-02-06T10:30:00.000-05:00",
            "EndDateTime": "2023-02-06T11:00:00.000-05:00",
            "DurationInMinutes": 30.0,
            "IsAllDayEvent": false,
            "IsPrivate": false,
            "Location": null,
            "Subject": "Test Meeting - Feb 6",
            "Type": "Meeting",
            "Event_Hash__c": 1458802897879456651,
            "OwnerId": "005o0000000q37tAAA",
            "EventWhoIds": [
                "0035c00002TOjhQAAT"
            ],
            "UndecidedEventInviteeIds": [
                "0035c00002TOjhQAAT"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


[
    {
        "id": "00U5c00000S5MptEAF",
        "success": true,
        "errors": []
    }
]
```

```
# Event activity for "Test Meeting - Feb 6 - Not a duplicate" does NOT show up in contact 0035c00002TOjhQAAT timeline
#EventRelation record with RelationId 0035c00002TOjhQAAT does NOT exist for EventId 00U5c00000S5MtVEAV
#Event 00U5c00000S5MtVEAV has been created with all of the expected details except its attendees.
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "event"
            },
            "Description": "Sample description",
            "StartDateTime": "2023-02-06T10:30:00.000-05:00",
            "EndDateTime": "2023-02-06T11:00:00.000-05:00",
            "DurationInMinutes": 30.0,
            "IsAllDayEvent": false,
            "IsPrivate": false,
            "Location": null,
            "Subject": "Test Meeting - Feb 6 - Duplicate",
            "Type": "Meeting",
            "Event_Hash__c": 1458802897879456651,
            "OwnerId": "005o0000000q37tAAA",
            "EventWhoIds": [
                "0035c00002TOjhQAAT"
            ],
            "UndecidedEventInviteeIds": [
                "0035c00002TOjhQAAT"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "event"
            },
            "Description": "Sample description",
            "StartDateTime": "2023-02-06T11:30:00.000-05:00",
            "EndDateTime": "2023-02-06T12:00:00.000-05:00",
            "DurationInMinutes": 30.0,
            "IsAllDayEvent": false,
            "IsPrivate": false,
            "Location": null,
            "Subject": "Test Meeting - Feb 6 - Not a duplicate",
            "Type": "Meeting",
            "Event_Hash__c": 1458802897879499999,
            "OwnerId": "005o0000000q37tAAA",
            "EventWhoIds": [
                "0035c00002TOjhQAAT"
            ],
            "UndecidedEventInviteeIds": [
                "0035c00002TOjhQAAT"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


[
    {
        "success": false,
        "errors": [
            {
                "statusCode": "DUPLICATE_VALUE",
                "message": "duplicate value found: Event_Hash__c duplicates value on record with id: 00U5c00000S5Mpt",
                "fields": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "00U5c00000S5MtVEAV",
        "success": true,
        "errors": []
    }
]
```

Comment: This has been logged as a known issue by Salesforce, and is being tracked here: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000sm9yc/when-unique-constraint-is-violated-the-sub-requests-to-create-event-records-via-the-composite-api-are-getting-created-partially